# Modify what happens when adding user to Newsletter list from create account Magento 2

Tags: magento2, newsletter

I want to override the functionality of subscribing to a newsletter so external email system can be kept in sync with Magento store.

I am wondeing which files i can override within Magento 2 to change this functionality?

From what i can tell i think it is:

```
Vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/CreatePost.php
```

This is the controller that the registration points to and has below code:

```
if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('is_subscribed', false)) {
            $this->subscriberFactory->create()->subscribeCustomerById($customer->getId());
        }
```

I was hoping i could overwrite one bit of code however so may go deeper to the **subscribeCustomerById** method however i cannot find the `Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory` file. There is however the `subscriber.php` file within `Magento\Newsletter\Model` which seems to have the neccasary code so will modify this here and see how it goes for now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that file is the file required to modify the subscriber factory.

I have overridden with a new module and modified like below:

## Di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber" type="Harrigo\SendyConnect\Model\Subscriberfactory" />
</config>
```

## Model

```
<?php 
namespace Harrigo\SendyConnect\Model;

use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\MailException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;

class Subscriberfactory extends \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber 
{ 
  public function isSubscribed()
  {
    if ($this->sendySubscribed() == "Subscribed") {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
  }


protected function _updateCustomerSubscription($customerId, $subscribe)
  { 
    if ($status == self::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED) {
        //subscribe here
        $this->sendySubscribe($customerData->getEmail());
    } elseif ($status == self::STATUS_UNSUBSCRIBED) {
        $this->sendyUnSubscribe($customerData->getEmail());
    }
  } 

public function subscribe($email)
{
  $this->sendySubscribe($email);
}

public function unsubscribe($email)
{
  $this->sendyUnsubscribe($email);
}
}
```

This seems to currently work for all subscribing / unsubscribing within customer area and the create an account form as well as the footer subscription (not sure what else to test?). I just added a small bit of code to each and left all functionality the same for Magento's newsletter for now.